# Cannot find symbol get text and settext

Tags: java, compiler-errors, applet, awt

I need help with this program to add text field item to listbox when button is clicked :

```
public void action performed(actionEvent e) {
    String temp = textField1.getText();
    textField1.setText(ls.getText());
    ls.setText(temp);
}
List ls;
```

Comment: Could you post the complete file and the complete error message Netbeans gives to you?

Comment: program to add textfield items to listbox when button is click

Comment: public class eg2 extends Applet implements ActionListener {
 public void init() {
  Label label1 = new Label("enter text : ");

  textField1 = new TextField("Hello");

  swapEm = new Button("show");
  swapEm.addActionListener(this);
  
  ls=new List();

  
  add(label1);
  add(textField1);
  add(swapEm);
  add(ls);
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  String temp = textField1.getText();
  textField1.setText(ls.getText());
  ls.setText(temp);
 }

 TextField textField1;
 Button swapEm;
 List ls;
    }

Comment: i need when the button is click then textfield value visible in listbox usin notpadd

Comment: @Prince - Please do not post your code in a comment. If you can, please edit your existing post and add your code. Also: `visible in listbox usin notpadd` - What is `notpadd`?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: .. 4) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 0):

The code in your provided **ActionPerformed** event doesn't make any real sense:

Your code:

```
public void action performed(actionEvent e){
    String temp=textField1.getText();
    textField1.setText(ls.getText());
    ls.setText(temp);
}

List ls;
```

You declare a string variable named **temp** and then initialize it with the contents from **textField1** which is okay but then in the next code line you want to change the contents of **textField1** to the value of **ls.getText()**. **ls** is declared as a List...there is no method named **getText()** for a AWT List. Perhaps you mean **ls.getSelectedItem()** but who knows...you're not giving enough information.

You are also trying to add to the List using a method named **setText()** as in the code line: `ls.setText(temp);`. Again, there is no such method for the AWT List that is named **setText()**. You are trying to use **TextField** methods for your **List** box and I'm afraid that's not going to work out as you have obviously already noticed.

Since you are using a AWT List all you need to do is: `ls.add(temp);` to add to your list box or better yet:

```
List ls; 

public void button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    String temp=textField1.getText();
    // Make sure temp actually contains something
    if (!temp.equals("")) { ls.add(temp); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that getText() is spelled exactly like that and the visibility modifier is public.